# How many arrangements of $MATHEMATICAL$ are there in which $ME$ appear together but the $ME$ is not immediately followed by an $A$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of $MATHEMATICAL$ are there in which $ME$ appear together but the $ME$ is not immediately followed by an $A$? (no MEA)

The answer is $(11!)/(3!2!) - (10!)/(2!2!)$

I am confused as to how this is the answer. There are 12 letters in $MATHEMATICAL$. I also don't understand the denominators. Is the first for the combinations of MEA and ME and the second is just ME and ME? There are $2$ M's and $1$ E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gluing the ME together as a single "character" yields 11 characters, with 3 repeated As and two repeated Ts. If we glue MEA together asa  single character, we get 10 characters in total, two repeated As, and two repeated Ts. The difference of these numbers counts the strings with ME together, but not with MEAs. This is the  answer that you have provided.